# How to add Conditions to registry value settings in a VS Installer Project

Tags: visual-studio

Unfortunately, I have the problem with setting condition for Registry value in Visual Studio Installer project.
The main goal is to suppress updating value for application registry key for application updating.Installer should not do anything for the value if it is already in application registry key.

In value properties, I see two significant:

- Condition
- Transitive, set as True

It seems that for condition the most suitable is:
   NOT [HKLM\Software\Company\PasswordReset]{callSignInstance}

Where key is *[HKLM\Software\Company\PasswordReset]* and name of the value is *callSignInstance*.
But in this case value just disappears from registry key. What is correct condition should be for this case?

Best regards,
Oleh